# Powerpoint 2016 is flashing unknown bar chart when advanding to next slide

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, flashing, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I created a presentation in Powerpoint.  I marked it as Final.  When I advance past a text-only slide to a slide with a bar chart, a completely different bar chart is flashing briefly.  The same unknown chart flashes briefly again when advancing to the next page with a completely different bar chart.  When I advance to the next slide, which is text only, there is no flashing. This presentation was created from scratch, and I never made a bar chart that looks like the one that is flashing briefly.

Powerpoint 2016
Windows 10

Comment: Have you completely powered the PC down and restarted recently? That'd be worth doing. And if this happens on only one slide, consider duplicating the slide then deleting and re-creating the chart.

Comment: You could share us a sample file with the issue.

Comment: This happens on 2 of 2 slides with bar charts.  I posted this in case this was a known issue.  I don't have time to engage in power cycling the PC, recreating charts, etc.  I moved on.  If there is a solution I will use it in the future.  Thanks for your help.